# Classic ASP issue iterating results of stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, vbscript, asp-classic, ado

I have a stored procedure that outputs a recordset but when I loop through that recordset it only writes back one item.

For example if I write:

```vb
vbsRS("fldDateSubmitted")&vbsRS("fldSubmittedBy")&vbsRS("fldDiaryEntry")
```

it will only show the `vbsRS("fldDateSubmitted")` value like if I write:

```vb
vbsRS("fldSubmittedBy")&vbsRS("fldDiaryEntry")
```

it will only show the `vbsRS("fldSubmittedBy")` value.

This doesn't make any sense, can anyone shed any light on the matter?

Here is the stored procedure call:

```vb
With objCMD
  .ActiveConnection = vbsConn
  .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
  .CommandText = "sp_GetTherapyDiaryEntries"

  ' Stored procedure parameters
  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@WaltonNumber",adInteger, adParamInput)
  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@EpisodeID",adInteger, adParamInput)
  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@TherapyType",adInteger, adParamInput)

  .Parameters("@WaltonNumber") = vbsZhospitalnumber
  .Parameters("@EpisodeID") = vbsZEpisodeID
  .Parameters("@TherapyType") = 2

  set vbsRS = .Execute
End With
```

Comment: try CStr(vbsRS("fldDateSubmitted")) & CStr(vbsRS("fldSubmittedBy")) & CStr(vbsRS("fldDiaryEntry"))

Comment: In case @SearchAndResQ suggestion does not work, you may try adding an empty string between them, like so: `vbsRS("fldSubmittedBy") & "" & vbsRS("fldDiaryEntry")`

Comment: marlenunez - empty string makes no difference nor does adding cStr()

Comment: Try using undocumented method like `vbsRS.Collect("fldDateSubmitted") & vbsRS.Collect("fldSubmittedBy") & vbsRS.Collect("fldDiaryEntry")`

Comment: That is no goo either.

Comment: assign the recordset values to variables and try. `Dim fldDateSubmitted : fldDateSubmitted = vbsRS("fldDateSubmitted")`

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer.

The reason this is happening is because I have some datatypes as VARCHAR(MAX), apparently this is a bug. Changing them to VARCHAR(2000) or whatever number solves the issue.

Comment: It is **not** a bug, you would have been using the wrong provider in your `vbsConn` connection string variable or your ado data type constants set in the `.CreateParameter()` method are wrong. If your using `VARCHAR(MAX)` in your stored procedure then you should be passing `adLongVarChar` (203) DataTypeEnum constant value.